# Laravel Homestead vagrant up box issue

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am installing laravel homestead. As I am new on this so maybe i took some steps wrong while installing and setting up laravel homestead on windows.

I followed a tutorial and download laravel homestead box directly and then install it manually by giving it a local disk url. It installed perfectly fine till then. But now when i am trying to "vagrant up" command it says that box doesnt found.

So after that I read somewhere that it we have to add manyual metadata somewhere but I dont know where. And after some changes I am facing this error.

[image]

Comment: vagrant cannot find a valid box, somehow your Vagrantfile or the yaml config does not provide the box information, detail the steps you've done and someone will tell you which one is missing

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please let me know where did i go wrong ? Or what steps should i do now or should i do it from the scratch again after removing everything? 

I followed this tutorial. 
https://medium.com/@charlesfreeborneteure/a-simplified-approach-to-installing-laravel-using-homestead-on-windows-f5fc50e59af0

Only step in this tutorial which i take out from the tutorial is that i download the box manually.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have downloaded the box manually, you need to add it to vagrant config, so vagrant knows about the box for later user. run the following command :

```
$ vagrant box add --box-version <VERSION_DOWNLOADED> laravel/homestead <path to downloaded file>
```

After this, make sure to go to the folder where homestead has been cloned (do not do that from the `.vagrant` directory, just go somewhere else, and avoid path with space, windows generally does not like it; `C:\homestead` will be just fine for a test) and you can run `vagrant up` from there

Comment: Nope  that doesnt work. It checks the version and says vagrant doesnt found. And then try to download from the live server again for vagrant up.

Comment: you can add the box with the version information or disabled the check of homestead on the box version by commenting the line https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/master/scripts/homestead.rb#L18